# `index_prefixes` in OpenSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am very new to the elastic/ opensearch technologies so pardon me if my understanding is inadequate.

I am trying to implement a search feature using OpenSearch where the user can type in any part of the first few characters of an entry to get the desired document. For example, for an entry like "David", they can type in any of the prefixes like "d", "da", "dav", etc and I have to search the correct document according to it.

I was using a `prefix` query for this earlier but now with new added requirements, the search queries need to be analyzed (`prefix` being a term query is not analyzed according to the documentation), I can see Elasticsearch has a `index_prefixes` parameter for mappings which can be used to generate prefixes for entries (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-prefixes.html), but I cannot find anything equivalent in OpenSearch. The best I could find is to use the `search_as_you_type` (https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/field-types/supported-field-types/search-as-you-type/) field that generates a sub field of `index_prefix`. But it also generates a `2gram` field which I do not need.

Does `OpenSearch` have anything apart from the `search_as_you_type` field type to help generate prefixes so that it would make such prefix searches faster?
Or is there any other way this can be implemented efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the edge_ngram tokenizer which helps to deploy **autocomplete feature**. It exists in both Opensearch and Elasticsearch.

https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/searching-data/autocomplete/#edge-n-gram-matching

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This looks like exactly what I require!

Comment: You're welcome :)
Also check ngram tokenizer if you are interested.